# Quickblox status 404 while getUsersByTags

Tags: android, videochat

Hello every one I'm trying to make a video call app for android using  [Quickblox](http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-android).

However when I execute the project I got error '404 Not found' while trying to get the list of users.

```java
 private void initOpponentListAdapter() {
        final ListView opponentsList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.opponentsList);
        List<QBUser> users = ((CallActivity) getActivity()).getOpponentsList();

        QBPagedRequestBuilder requestBuilder = new QBPagedRequestBuilder();
        requestBuilder.setPerPage(100);

        if (users == null) {
            List<String> tags = new LinkedList<String>();
            tags.add("webrtcusers");

            QBUsers.getUsersByTags(
                tags, requestBuilder,
                new QBEntityCallback<ArrayList<QBUser>>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(ArrayList<QBUser> qbUsers, Bundle bundle) {
                        Log.d("Track", "download users from QickBlox");
                        ArrayList<QBUser> orderedUsers = reorderUsersByName(qbUsers);

                        if(isAdded()) {
                            ((CallActivity) getActivity()).setOpponentsList(orderedUsers);
                            prepareUserList(opponentsList, orderedUsers);
                            progresDialog.dismiss();
                        } else {
                            Log.e("getActivity() error", "get Activity is null, because adapter wasn't added");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(List<String> strings) {
                        Log.d("Track", "onError()");
                    }
                }
            );
        } else {

            ArrayList<QBUser> userList = ((CallActivity) getActivity()).getOpponentsList();
            prepareUserList(opponentsList, userList);
            progresDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }
```

This is the result in logcat.

```
06-06 03:44:11.154: W/EGL_genymotion(3050): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-06 03:44:11.238: W/EGL_genymotion(3050): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-06 03:44:11.490: D/dalvikvm(3050): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 306K, 9% free 4158K/4568K, paused 6ms, total 6ms
06-06 03:44:11.890: D/QBASDK(3050): *********************************************************
06-06 03:44:11.890: D/QBASDK(3050): *** RESPONSE *** ac58f201-a366-40c0-a6e7-22ea22b2dd41 ***
06-06 03:44:11.890: D/QBASDK(3050): STATUS : 404 
06-06 03:44:11.890: D/QBASDK(3050): HEADERS
06-06 03:44:11.890: D/QBASDK(3050):     Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*
06-06 03:44:11.890: D/QBASDK(3050):     Cache-Control=no-cache
06-06 03:44:11.890: D/QBASDK(3050):     Connection=keep-alive
06-06 03:44:11.890: D/QBASDK(3050):     Content-Type=application/json; charset=utf-8
06-06 03:44:11.890: D/QBASDK(3050):     Date=Sat, 06 Jun 2015 07:44:11 GMT
06-06 03:44:11.890: D/QBASDK(3050):     QB-Token-ExpirationDate=2015-06-06 09:44:09 UTC
06-06 03:44:11.890: D/QBASDK(3050):     QuickBlox-REST-API-Version=0.1.1
06-06 03:44:11.890: D/QBASDK(3050):     Server=nginx/1.0.15
06-06 03:44:11.890: D/QBASDK(3050):     Status=404 Not Found
06-06 03:44:11.890: D/QBASDK(3050):     Transfer-Encoding=chunked
06-06 03:44:11.890: D/QBASDK(3050):     X-Rack-Cache=miss
06-06 03:44:11.890: D/QBASDK(3050):     X-Request-Id=4dde392fc0e70b3032595495dc3e4ebc
06-06 03:44:11.890: D/QBASDK(3050):     X-Runtime=0.023759
06-06 03:44:11.890: D/QBASDK(3050):     X-UA-Compatible=IE=Edge,chrome=1
06-06 03:44:11.890: D/QBASDK(3050): BODY
06-06 03:44:11.890: D/QBASDK(3050):     ' '
06-06 03:44:11.890: D/Track(3050): onError()
```

Please any suggestion and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem i just forgot to add tags to my users